# How To Pass Arguments to Javascript File From PHP Exec

Tags: javascript, php

After a form is submitted from my php file it checks it, and then is supposed to call an `exec` function that will execute a binary file using the second file listed in the code. Shown below:

```
if (isset($_POST['admin']) && !empty($_POST['admin'])) {
  echo exec('/home/mainshee/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/phantom/phantomjs-directory/bin/phantomjs /home/mainshee/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/phantom/phantomjs-directory/examples/bigdaddy.js');
}
```

The problem here is that the preceding javascript file `bigdaddy.js` has to take three arguments of its own in order to function. To solve this issue, I tried the following:

```
echo exec('/home/mainshee/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/phantom/phantomjs-directory/bin/phantomjs /home/mainshee/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/phantom/phantomjs-directory/examples/bigdaddy.js' $_POST['admin'] $_POST['user'] $_POST['password']);
```

This bricked my site.
Does anybody have any ideas how this may be done? All of the possible solutions I have found detail PHP to PHP, NOT PHP to Javascript. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

you have to post back the javascript variable to your server before the server can handle the value. To do this you can either program a javascript function that submits a form - or you can use ajax / jquery. jQuery.post

Maybe the most easiest approach for you is something like this

```
function myJavascriptFunction() { 
  var javascriptVariable = "John";
  window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?name=" + javascriptVariable; 
}
```

On your myphpfile.php you can use $_GET['name'] after your javascript was executed.

Comment: Neither of those solutions would work as the information being submitted through the form is sensitive information. I will have to do more research on a javascript function submitting a form.